# Variance of new $y$ - $\hat{y}$

Tags: regression, self-study, variance

Suppose we have a linear regression $Y = X\beta + e$, and we have new data come in. $Y_{new} = X_{new}\beta + e_{new}$. And we know that $Y_{new}$ and $\hat{Y_{new}}$ are independent. So $Var(Y_{new} - \hat{Y_{new}})$ = $Var(Y_{new}) + Var(\hat{Y_{new}})$ = $(I + H)\sigma^2$, where $H$ is the projection matrix. But according to the formula $Var(Ay) = AVar(y)A^{T}$, so we can get $Var(Y_{new} - \hat{Y_{new}})$ = $(I-H)\sigma^2(I-H)^{T}$ = $(I - H)\sigma^2$.
My question is that are they he same? Or I missed something? Thank you!!

Comment: Please explain what "$\hat Y$" refers to.  Normally it would refer to an estimator based on a sample of $Y,$ but that estimator is worthless unless it is *not* independent of $Y$!

Comment: Why are Ynew and Y(hat)new known to be independent?

Comment: Sorry, $\hat{Y}$ is the estimator of $Y$

Comment: since $\hat{Y}_{new}$ = $X_{new}(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$, which is only correlated with Y?

Comment: Please include this definition of $\hat Y_{new}$ in your question--and notice that it directly contradicts your first comment, which implies $\hat Y_{new}$ depends only on $Y_{new}.$  When you do this, please also clarify the question: to what does "they" refer?  What things are you supposing might be the same?

Comment: If Y and Ynew are from the same population or in any way related to each other through their relationship with X, Ynew and Y(hat)new will of course be correlated and not at all independent. How correlated they are will depend on the strength of relationship between Y and X and whether that relationship is consistent with the relationship between Ynew and Xnew. In other words, how well the model generalizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that $\hat{Y}_{new} \neq H Y_{new}$, so your working falls apart.  The hat matrix comes from the data that was used to fit the model.  Using the model *estimated from the initial data*, you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\hat{Y}_{new} = X_{new} \hat{\beta} 
= X_{new} (X^\text{T} X) X^\text{T} Y \neq X (X^\text{T} X) X^\text{T} Y_{new}. \end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

To find the variance of interest, you should substitute the proper expressions for the two parts and simplify from there using standard variance rules.  (Be careful to be clear about what you condition on; e.g., whether or not you are conditioning on the original data, or the new explanatory vector.)

Answer (score 1):

Situation: You have two sets of data, (o)ld and (n)ew. You use old data to fit a linear model. Plugging the vectors of covariates from the new data into the fitted model, you get the predicted value, $\hat Y_n$. You also have $Y_n$. When you derive the $Var(Y_n-\hat Y_n)$, you used two methods and got the different results.

Methods 1:
$Var(Y_n-\hat Y_n) = Var(Y_n) + Var(\hat Y_n) = \sigma^2I + Var(X_n\hat \beta) =  \sigma^2I + \sigma^2X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_n^T = \sigma^2(I+X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_n^T)$

Method 2: $Y_n=X_n\beta+\epsilon_n$ and

$\hat Y_n = X_n\hat\beta = X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_o^TY_o =X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_o^T(X_o\beta + \epsilon_n) = X_n\beta+ X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_o^T\epsilon_o  $

Then $Y_n-\hat Y_n = \epsilon_n - X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_o^T\epsilon_o = (I, - X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_o^T)(\epsilon_n^T, \epsilon_o^T)^T $

Given $Var[(\epsilon_n^T, \epsilon_o^T)^T] = \sigma^2I$, we have

$Var(Y_n-\hat Y_n) = \sigma^2(I, - X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_o^T)(I, - X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_o^T)^T =\sigma^2 (I+X_n(X_o^TX_o)^{-1}X_n^T) $ 
So two methods give you the same results.